# Warnings on pdfminer

Tags: python, pdf, python-3.x, pdfminer

I have found and (slightly) modified this script in stackoverflow for it to work on python 3.3:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, process_pdf
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from io import StringIO

def convert_pdf(path):

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, laparams=laparams)

    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    process_pdf(rsrcmgr, device, fp)
    fp.close()
    device.close()

    string = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return string


print(convert_pdf('abc.pdf'))
```

It works fine, however i seem to be having 2 issues:

- While running the script I get tons of warnings:

  WARNING:root:undefined: PDFCIDFont:    basefont='LKOELN+Wingdings-Regular', cidcoding='Adobe-Identity', 139
  WARNING:root:undefined: PDFCIDFont: basefont='LKKPCF+Wingdings2', cidcoding='Adobe-Identity', 132

Which  in the printed text looks like `(cid:139)`, how do I catch this warnings and replace that text with something else?

- Note that I have a codec line, which in the original script goes inside the `TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, laparams=laparams)`, however I get:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/rodrigo/Desktop/csp_pdf/csp_pdf2.py", line 46, in 
      convert_pdf('abc.pdf')
    File "C:/Users/rodrigo/Desktop/csp_pdf/csp_pdf2.py", line 33, in convert_pdf
      device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec = 'utf-8', laparams=laparams)
  TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'codec'

Is this related to the first issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pdfminer3k logs to the Python **root** logger unfortunately. PDFMiner should implement logging correctly IMHO.  So it is not possible to disable logging in the normal manner like.

```
logging.getLogger("pdfminer").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Bummer!

I did this and it works™:

```
    logging.propagate = False 
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

It sets the root logger to level Error. This will stop PDFMiner warn logging, since it logs to the root logger, but not your own logging.

I needed to set propagation to False, because after PDFMiner usage, I had duplicate logging entries. This was caused by the root logger.

Comment: Just `logging.getLogger('pdfminer').setLevel(logging.ERROR)` now seems to work?

Answer (score 0):

As regards the the WARNING
If you look in the file 'pdfparser.py' part of pdfminer module (line 341) - in my file)
I believe this is where it is being generated from.
But before you do that, try this code below. This is for Python 3 and assume you got the 
version for python 3 - 'pdfminer3k 1.3.0', https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer3k
I do get warning like 'WARNING:root:Cannot locate objid=149', with the code below, 
but the warning does not seem to get into the text stream. Possibly the .pdf file is corrupt.
Notes on your code
In the function 'TextConverter' there is no 'codec' argument
And your line 'TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, laparams=laparams)' is correct
Hope this helps

```
import io
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, process_pdf
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams

def convert_pdf(pdfFile, retstr):
    password = ''
    pagenos = set()
    maxpages = 0
    laparams = LAParams()
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, laparams=laparams)    
    process_pdf(rsrcmgr, device, pdfFile, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password, check_extractable=True)
    device.close()
    return retstr
pdfFile = open('C:\\SomeDirectory\\Some_PDF_File.pdf','rb')
retstr = io.StringIO()
retstr = convert_pdf(pdfFile, retstr)
print(retstr.getvalue())
pdfFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running pdfMiner on python 3.8 and inside of my application where I have assigned handlers to the root logger it is extremely slow. After investigation I found that each module creates a logger with unique name ('**NAME**'). Not as the root logger. All of these default to level.DEBUG and on conversion from the earlier python2.7 version print statements have been replaced with log. calls.

To remedy this I added the following code just after the imports and before even initializing the pdfminer classes, This makes my application run acceptably fast.

```
# set all pdfminer logging to WARN
pdflogs = [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict if name.startswith('pdfminer')]
for ll in pdflogs:
    ll.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```